# download release binaries from github via VCS api

Tags: artifactory

I'm using Artifactory and have a vcs-remote repo configured.  With this, I can hit the JFrog API and pull things like tags, zipped up code from different releases or branches, etc. What I cannot figure out how to do is actually download only specific binaries from the Releases in Github.

Example:  https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases.  I just want to download "terragrunt_linux_amd64" on the v0.35.13 release.

Interestingly, I can download all of the code associated with the release, so I could build the binary myself. I don't want to do that, though, if the binary is sitting right there ready for use.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic remote repository "github-remote" with URL pointing to **https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download** and using the Artifactory URL as http://myartifactory/artifactory/github-remote/v0.35.13/terragrunt_darwin_amd64 and you should be able to download the actual binary.